# Failed to launch app from custom SageMaker image: ResourceNotFoundError with UID/GID in AppImageConfig

Tags: python, docker, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to create a [custom SageMaker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-byoi-create.html) and launch a kernel from it, because I want to see if I can use black, the python code formatter, in [SageMaker](https://github.com/psf/black) Studio via a custom SageMaker image.

So far, I've been able to attach the image to the SageMaker domain and start launching the kernel from the custom image, following [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-byoi-create.html). However, as soon as the notebook opens, it displays this error in the notebook:

> Failed to launch app [black-conda-ml-t3-medium-7123fdb901f81ab5]. ResourceNotFoundError: SageMaker is unable to launch the app using the image [123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/conda-sample@sha256:12345]. Ensure that the UID/GID provided in the AppImageConfig matches the default UID/GID defined in the image. (Context: RequestId: 21234b0f568, TimeStamp: 1677767016.2990377, Date: Thu Mar 2 14:23:36 2023)

Here are the relevant code snippets:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.9.2

COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env update -f environment.yml --prune
```

environment.yml:

```
name: base
channels:
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - python=3.9
 - numpy
 - awscli
 - boto3
 - ipykernel
 - black
```

and AppImageConfig:

```
{
    "AppImageConfigName": "conda-env-kernel-config",
    "KernelGatewayImageConfig": {
        "KernelSpecs": [
            {
                "Name": "python3",
                "DisplayName": "Python [conda env: myenv]"
            }
        ],
        "FileSystemConfig": {
            "MountPath": "/root",
            "DefaultUid": 0,
            "DefaultGid": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I tried following [this troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-custom-image-samples/blob/main/DEVELOPMENT.md), but it doesn't seem to address my issues because all of the diagnostics worked alright. For example, when I ran `id -u` and `id -g` inside my local container, the results `0` and `0` lined up with the AppImageConfig settings of `"DefaultUid": 0, "DefaultGid": 0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to *have* the AppImageConfig locally and only push the built image to ECR -- you also need to push the AppImageConfig using the following command:

```
aws sagemaker create-app-image-config \
    --cli-input-json file://app-image-config-input.json
```

And then use that when you're attaching the custom image to the SageMaker domain.

If you're doing that in the Console, then you don't actually use the AppImageConfig file itself -- you just enter the info from it into the create image dialog:

```
        "MountPath": "/root",
        "DefaultUid": 0,
        "DefaultGid": 0
        "Name": "python3",
        "DisplayName": "Python [conda env: myenv]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try "DefaultUid": 1000 and "DefaultGid": 100.